# Can't make the system run rc.local on restart

Tags: permissions, scripts, reboot, amazon-ec2

I've got AWS EC2 with Ubuntu Server 16.0.4 instance running and I want to make sure that there is script executed every time the instance is restarted or ubuntu is restarted.
I searched all over the internet and it seemed very easy - just change `/etc/rc.local` and it should work. I've done it and it does not.

`/etc/rc.local` file - removed -e in `#!/bin/sh` and just one line which executes the script (EDIT)

```sh
    #!/bin/sh
    #
    # rc.local
    #
    # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
    # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
    # value on error.
    #
    # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
    # bits.
    #
    # By default this script does nothing.

    echo RC_LOCAL
    sh /home/ubuntu/scripts/boot.sh

    exit 0
```

permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     339 Nov  7 10:04 rc.local`

and my `boot.sh` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo SYSTEM_BOOT

~/xxx/xxx/xxx console &
sudo ./xxx/xxx/xxx.sh
```

permissions: `-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu   92 Nov  7 09:17 boot.sh`

Weird thing is that I can run `/etc/rc.local` and `boot.sh` is called and everything is like I wanted it to be but there it is not executed when I run `sudo reboot` and connect to the AWS via SSH for the next time.

EDIT:
After `sudo reboot` and connecting using ssh:
`➜  AWS ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx`
I got:

```
`Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1039-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

62 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Tue Nov  7 10:22:38 2017 from 157.25.99.66`

ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to hide with your xxx. `/etc/rc.local` will be run as root, so calling sudo is strange. `./xxx/xxx/xxx.sh` will be called with the current working directory of `/etc/rc.local` which for me is unknown.

Comment: Are you sure it's not executed? That would be rather strange. Try with something simpler, let's say just an `echo "I'm working all right"`. (No `&`, please.) And by the way, what do you suppose is the current working directory when trying to run `./xxx/xxx/xxx.sh`?

Comment: @pim I know that it is weird. Have a look at my question edit. And yes - I can make sure that it is not executed because it is supposed to start tomcat and activemq which can be accessed from the web.

Comment: I can't see the problem with your login... Are you trying to run a command before the login and/or at reboot?

Comment: @pim but actually one thing is weird - inside my boot.sh there is echo "SYSTEM_BOOT" and I still cannot see it. Scripts work fine but echo doesn't show up.

Comment: I don't think stdout is working in init scripts (see also : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418086/2069348)

Comment: *"but echo doesn't show up"* - where are you expecting it to show up? `rc.local` doesn't run in a terminal

Comment: You could also have a look into `cron`. There is a `@reboot` option for running the defined cronjob on every reboot. You do `crontab -e` and add a line `@reboot /home/ubuntu/scripts/boot.sh`